# Converting variable to string in Puppet

Tags: ruby, puppet

Is it possible to convert `Boolean` variable to `String` in `Puppet`? I want to use it when replacing string. I can use conditional statement but maybe it is not necessary.

```
$variable = true
$my_string = "status _"
$string = regsubst($my_string, '_', $variable)
```

Something like this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd recomend using the [puppetlabs-stdlib](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/stdlib#bool2str) function for this:

### bool2str

Converts a boolean to a string using optionally supplied arguments. The optional second and third arguments represent what true and false are converted to respectively. If only one argument is given, it is converted from a boolean to a string containing 'true' or 'false'.

Examples:

```
bool2str(true)                    => 'true'
bool2str(true, 'yes', 'no')       => 'yes'
bool2str(false, 't', 'f')         => 'f'
Requires a single boolean as input. Type: rvalue.
```